# can someone please tell me why is "previousValue" here in the code is "array type"?

Tags: methods, reduce

// logic to console duplicate in a new array
let myArray = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd']
let myArrayWithNoDuplicates = myArray.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue) {
if (previousValue.indexOf(currentValue) === -1) {
previousValue.push(currentValue)
}
return previousValue
}, [])

```
  console.log(myArrayWithNoDuplicates)
```

Comment: Your code is difficult to read. Rlease read the https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help section *Syntax highlighting for code**.

Answer (score 0):

previousValue is the previous value of your accumulator. Your accumulator is [] an array so previousValue has to be array